# What has better performance on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, function, stored-procedures

I want to compare a number of values (up to ten) with a function that will return the smallest value of them.

My colleague wrote the function like:

```
set @smallest = null

if @smallest is null or @date0 < @smallest 
begin
    set @smallest = @date0
end

if @smallest is null or @date1 < @smallest 
begin
    set @smallest = @date1
end
... (repeating 10 times)
```

Beside of that the if statement could be written smarter (the null check can fall away after the first comparison) I was wondering if creating an in-memory indexed table and let the function return me the first value would be more efficient? 
Is there any documentation that I could read for this?

Comment: How is the information currently stored? Is it something you could just run MIN() over?

Comment: no, these are separate fields within rows of data. Currently three values are compared, but the method is written to support up to 10 at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

> creating an in-memory indexed table

There is no point having an index on 10 records.  Create a derived table (will sit in memory) as shown below, then run MIN across the table:

```
select @smallest = MIN(Adate)
from (
    select @date0 Adate union all
    select @date1 union all
    select @date2 union all
    -- ....
    select @date9) X
```

Comment: I like the approach, but is the performance better than 10 IF statements?

Comment: There should be no significant difference. Maybe 1ms or 2ms when you do it 100 times in a row or so, if any, and even then, I'm not really sure which will be faster.